# How to get domain name in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to determine the current domain name from within the Startup.Cs module of an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor pages application. The website will be bound to several different domains and I want to load the appropriate _layout/theme based on this.

I have been searching, but I can't figure out how to determine which domain was used to reach the site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just need to look at the host header, passed in the request.

Comment: Okay, I've seen several notes about viewing the host header from the request, however, I'm not sure how to access the request in the Startup.cs module.

Comment: The host header isn't available during startup. You can't determine the domain at startup anyway, due to "the web sitesite will be bound to several domains." The domain is associated with a request, not globally with the site. See [How to  get host header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638669/how-to-get-host-header-from-httpcontext-asp-net)  and [Is it possible to get host header during startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241346/is-it-possible-to-get-the-host-in-application-start)

Answer (score 7):

You have access to the request object if your controller inherits from `Controller`

```
public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = $"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}{this.Request.PathBase}";

        return View();
    }
```